# Incorrect data when run as subquery

Tags: sql

I have a query that takes data about given media from a table it joins it with the user table
:

```
SELECT media.id, media.user_id,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position 
INNER JOIN users
ON media.user_id = users.id
FROM media_table 
ORDER BY media.distance ASC, media.media_likes_count DESC, media.media_views_count Desc;
```

This query produces a nice looking table as follows:

```
media_id, user_id, position
39199   , 3949   , 1
39299   , 3149  , 2
39359   , 3944   , 3
39369   , 3349   , 4
39379   , 3149   , 5
39389   , 3449   , 6
```

From this derived table, I want to get position of media_id = 39389.

However if I include that query in  subquery like this:

```
Select position from (SELECT media.id, media.user_id,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position from 
INNER JOIN users
ON media.user_id = users.id
FROM media_table 
ORDER BY media.distance ASC, media.media_likes_count DESC, media.media_views_count Desc;)
where media_id = 39389
```

Then the columns 'shuffle' and 39389 does not have position 6 anymore.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `FROM` statements in your query?

Comment: Both the original and the "non-working" queries have errors, neither will run.  What table is the `media` reference pointing too?  I'm not aware of any RDBMS that allows you to put the `FROM` clause anywhere but first of all table references.  And you're not allowed to terminate subqueries with statement delimiters.  What is your actual statement, please?

Comment: Just exclude the syntax errors from the statement and focus on the logic on why it is not working. There is a select performed on a subquery that changes the results. that is really odd

Comment: The most likely reason is that you have ties for `media.distance`, `media.media_likes_count`, and `media.media_views_count`, so the sorting is unstable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not withstanding the errors in your query, assuming those are just typos, perhaps you're issue is not initializing your `user defined variable`.  This condensed version works for me:

```
select postition
from (
  select yourresults.*, @rn:=@rn+1 postition
  from yourresults 
    join (select @rn:= 0) t
  order by media_id
  ) t
where media_id = 39389
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91c27/1)

While this does not work:

```
select postition
from (
  select yourresults.*, @rn:=@rn+1 postition
  from yourresults 
  order by media_id
  ) t
where media_id = 39389
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91c27/2)